# Docker container DHCP like bridged VirtualBox

Tags: linux, networking, docker, dhcp

In our company we recently dockerized our product especially for development. The product is CentOS based solution. We also use VirtualBox to run CentOS and Windows part of it. These parts have to communicate with each other over the network. Company network uses DHCP and for VBox I used to have 3 IPs (my dev machine, CentOS, Win). Win part still has to run on VBox. But CentOS is running in Docker.

Problem is that docker container does not have its own LAN IP. So I'm not able to run more than one container otherwise, there will be overlapping ports. And I don't want to remap them for each container.

I played with macvlan module, but it requires extra IP address and manual route just to access macvlan from my dev machine. But the container is inaccessible from VBox machine. Everything is running on my dev machine.

Is there any way to get DHCP IP into docker and also be accessible from all devices on the same LAN segment?

Comment: Have you got the answer? If yes could you please share it?